# how to make a tkinter window with a lot of properties

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a game overlay with python and it needs to support a lot of features for my game overlay to work the way it was intended to.

It needs to have a transparent window, pass clicks both right and left (to the application underneath it), pass all keyboard keys (to the application underneath it), and FINALY can still collect all the mouse movement and keyboard press events.

I don't even know if all of this is possible, or if I need to do this in another pip or language

I am on windows 10

`jesus.py :`

```
from tkinter import *

jesus = Tk()
jesus.title("Minecraft's Jesus")
jesus.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
jesus.attributes("-topmost", True)
jesus.attributes("-alpha", 0.002)
jesus.configure(background='grey')
jesus.mainloop()
```

Edit: I was completely unaware of hooks at the time and now this question is useless. A thanks to `Tim Roberts` for suggesting to use hooks.

Comment: Are you doing this on Windows?  If so, then you almost certainly want to do this with a Windows hook, and not with a transparent window.  pywinauto or winput or pyWinhook might do it.

Comment: if you are making a game i suggest using pygame